# Popup Modal in C# MVC Template causes endless loop

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm currently building an application where I want to be able to pop up a window whenever someone clicks a keyword from anywhere within the website. That window will be refreshed by Ajax and load the right information from the database to the popup window.

I might be using the wrong logic here, but I've been running circles for days on this issue.

I'm using this (shortened) Cshtml Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>
        <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/ievalidation.js"></script><![endif]-->
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/bundles/customcss")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        @Html.Partial("../Accueil/Nav")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="InfoBulleModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        @Html.Action("InfoBulle")
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)  

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script")
    </body>
</html>
```

The section where the problem arises is:

```
<div id="InfoBulleModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    @Html.Action("InfoBulle")
</div>
```

I've tried making it partial, I've tried using different methods to render it, but I always end up in one of 2 situations:

1. The Modal loads without using the controller method that loads the data from the database and returns a NullReferenceException error
2. The Modal goes into the controller, loads the correct data, and somehow ends up going back to a _ViewStart.cshtml page that sends it back to the Layout page, and creates an endless loop.

Here's the content of _ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Here's the controller method for the modal:

```
public ActionResult InfoBulle()
    {
        InfoBulle InfoB = new InfoBulle();

        InfoB = dal.GetInfoBulle(1); //I'm using the id = 1 for testing purposes, I can confirm that the desired data is loaded at this point

        return View(InfoB);  //This part reloads the template, hence it reloads itself infinitely
    }
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction to it would be very appreciated!

Comment: You should declare your `InfoBulle` view as a partial view in order to avoid this.

Comment: You're right! Turns out I was trying to use Html.Partial along with a return PartialView, but the correct way was to use Html.Action("View", "Controller") in the Layout, and: "Return PartialView" in the controller!